# PHP page displays on ubuntu, not on Windows 7

Tags: php, wamp, xampp

We've inherited a PHP page which runs fine on Ubuntu, but dumps source code onto the display on a Windows 7 system running either XAMMP using PHP 5.4, or WAMP using PHP 5.3.

The point where the dump occurs seems to be when it tries to parse a "->" (object property) character combination. When I change that to "[]" to access as an array element, it gets past that, but then dumps source code onto the display which appears after the "=>" (mapping) character combination. Commenting that out doesn't work, only deleting the whole line gets it past there.

Finally, when it's just printing out html with "<" and ">" signs, that also causes the screen dump. If I replace those characters with the html entities, the source code doesn't dump any more, but the program doesn't display the menu and doesn't function at all. Note that I can successfully log into the app via it's login page, although even that displays "POST" and some other "<" and ">" characters in the username field.

I've tried running unix2dos on the whole app, but that didn't have any effect. Also tried converting the text of one of the offending pages to UTF-8, but still no luck.

In answer to some of the questions posed:

The working ubuntu version is PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1

The first piece of code that works in Ubuntu and not in Windows is this:

```
public function __construct($gid)
{
    $this->id = $gid;
    return $this->retrieve();
}
```

where the code dump onto the display starts with:

```
id = $gid; return $this->retrieve(); }
```

Yes, PHPInfo does work, showing for the WAMP server with PHP Version 5.3.13

I tried changing the  short-open-tag but it made no difference.

The product was written for us by an outsourcing group, and it appears to be based on some kind of framework. But I couldn't find any references to any of the classnames on Google, so maybe they wrote the whole thing in-house.

Going to the apache log, the actual error happens on this line:

```
$_SESSION['admin_gid'] = Membership::getGroup($rUser['id']);
```

where the error message is:

> Membership' not found

Membership is a class which is declared later in the same file as the one getting dumped on the display at the point shown above, so for some reason the PHP parser doesn't understand it's reading PHP code from that point.

Comment: Could you post the shortest piece of code that works on one platform and not the other?

Comment: it seems the short-open-tag directive turned off in windows http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Can you get a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to work on the Win7 web server?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us exactly what the errors are that you're getting, and the code that triggers them. It is highly unlikely to be a Windows/Linux conversion problem, as PHP is designed to be portable. What is the software you're running? Is it internally-written code or a third party product? The changes you've made (eg replacing `->` with `[]`) sound implausible; seeing the code in context would be useful. Also, you haven't mentioned what version of PHP it works on under Ubuntu (even thought you have told us the PHP versions you've tried in windows). This would help too.

Comment: Posted an edit with the responses. Thanks.

Comment: "I tried changing the short-open-tag but it made no difference."
Did you restart Apache after making that change?

Comment: Yes: tried both short_open_tag = On, and short_open_tag = Off.

Comment: I used to have many problems a bit similar to what you have now because I'm developing in both ubuntu and windows and Mac, the problems occurs only for Windows, and most of the cases its one of the following reasons: an encoding issues, file names and PATHS, you likely have problems with the PATHs as you mentioned that the framework in in-house written they might use static PATH separators instead of detecting the one use for the current system, may be you need to check that !

Comment: Try different PHP verison. I looks like an environment related issue to me.

Comment: @Bradley - for some reason, the Wamp server php.ini change didn't affect the short_open_tag; however, right-clicking on php and changing the setting from the list that appears there did. If you want credit (and the bounty) you can post your comment as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JackBeNimble wamp has 2 php.ini's. One is under apache and one is under php. The one under php is for the command line version of PHP.

Comment: @JackBeNimble Is it due to the script exection time in PHP being different on the two different servers? Maybe its running out of time before being able to finish running the script?

Comment: Have you converted the offending page to UTF-8 without BOM or with BOM?

Comment: @chumkui - can you post a answer? You were the first to suggest the short tag flag.

Comment: I agree with @AbuRomaïssae, it seems like either an encoding or PATH issue to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I tried changing the short-open-tag but it made no difference.
```

In a scenario like this what you can do is write a small script and run it and see whether it works. try short tag and below method. Keep in mind that if you mess with your `php.ini` you will have to restart the server. It's better to change the setting by right clicking on the server icon on the task-bar. It could be due to [php short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). Try enabling and disabling and running the script. Also change the below script and see how that affects with your changed settings.

EG :

```
<?php
echo "hi";
// phpinfo(); <-- preferred if you can
?>
```

Then you can see whether your server is working you as intend it to. If it O/P `hi` you are good to try your big code and see.

By the way code which you have provided does not seems have errors.

Comment: This was initially suggested in the comments, but the way to get it to work was to set it by setting the flag by right-clicking on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it is interesting.

If this is a big application, then you might have to check all the files being included. There can be number of issues.

Try doing the following steps

1. Set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
2. Try using `debug_backtrace` http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php
3. Check Output buffering status. Is it on or off

On the other side, have you copied the entire project from linux to windows? may be some files are outside the project folder which are not there in windows? I know lots of people do create such loopholes so they can be contacted for "SUPPORT" :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is case insensitive for the class naming. You can normally do

```
$membership = new membership();
```

even if the class is named 'Membership' and vice-versa. Try to changing the class name, maybe class file name is case sensitive on operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Its really strange.. though you can check Membership class been loaded or not using function:

```
array get_declared_classes ( void )


<?php
print_r(get_declared_classes());
?>
```

It will Returns an array with the name of the defined classes.

ref:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php